# How do I prevent the panel from sliding up out of view when a select element is clicked on a Panel in a Widget using Firefox SDK

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have been struggling with this for more than a day now, most of which spent on SO and Google looking for a solution and trying various things.

I am using SDK 1.14 and testing on Firefox 23.  I have a widget that has a panel.  The panel's contentURL is a local HTML file in the data directory.  When a select element is placed in the HTML and that element is clicked by the user, the entire panel (or at least its content) moves to the top left of the *browser* window out of view from the panel that is still in the lower left of the screen.  I can tell that the panel (or at least its content) moves to the upper left of the *browser* window because the options are displayed there.  I presume that it is binding to the origin of the *browser* window when the select element is clicked.

[image: Widget Icon]
[image: Widget Panel]
[image: Floating Options]

As a test I reduced it down to the bare minimum for a Widget and Panel with a select element.  The main.js code is:

```
exports.main = function () {
    var self = require('self'),
        testPanel = require('panel').Panel({
            contentURL: self.data.url('test.html')
        });

    require('widget').Widget({
        label: 'Test Panel',
        id: 'TestPanel',
        panel: testPanel,
        contentURL: self.data.url('images/icon_16.png')
    });
};
```

The HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <select>
        <option value='1'>1</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

When the HTML initially loads the select element is displayed correctly in the Widget's Panel.  When I click on the select element the option elements move up to the top left of the *browser* window.  The position of the panel's content does not reset when the panel is closed and subsequently reopened using the Widget's icon.

Comment: Looks like a bug... https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/

Comment: @nmaier I'm not sure if this is a bug with Firefox or with the SDK.  Some additional information...  it seems to be any Panel regardless of whether it is attached to the widget or not.  Also, I have updated to Firefox 24 and the problem remains.

Comment: Even more information... So it doesn't appear to be changing the origin relative to the Firefox window, but rather to the Desktop. If I move the Firefox window to my 2nd monitor and repeat the procedures above the floating option appears in the same space relative to the Desktop and not the Firefox window. I'm having a coworker test my xpi on his machine.  I can't imagine that this "bug" would go unnoticed, it would mean that nobody would be able to put a select element on any Panel. This leads me to believe that it's local to me, but we'll see.

Comment: Coworker confirms that he is seeing the same result on his Firefox 23 from the generated XPI.

Comment: Seems like a position bug with the popup window. Just file a bug with the SDK folks and provide your simplified test case. Either they will fix it, or they will move it to the appropriate component.

Comment: So it appears to already be submitted as [Bug 886329](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=886329).  It came up when I tried to submit it as a possible similar issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just so it isn't lost in the comments: This is a known bug, namely [Bug 886329](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=886329). I was told that since this was already marked P1 (priority 1) "it should be very high up the list".
Personal experience tells me that is is unlikely to be fixed in a Firefox 23 point release (if there is even one). Maybe it will be fixed in Firefox 24, maybe even later...

There are no real work-arounds I could think of, short of using some html UI library to simulate the dropdowns (which are really OS-level child-windows when using `<select>`, but not when using html). There are plenty of such implementations on the net.